# Xamarin Android Fragments Libraries

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, libraries

I'm new in Xamarin IDE, i get a problem when i use Fragment, i need to use the Support Library, but when i compile the code, i get those errors:

---

Error:

1:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r28.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.2.1.0\content directory.  Fragments

2:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Reason: File C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\17BE247580748F1EDB72E9F374AA0223.zip is not a ZIP archive Fragments

3:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.2.1.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist. Fragments

4:Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.2.1.0\content./ doesn't exist. Fragments

5:Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.2.1.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.   Fragments

6:Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.2.1.0\content./ doesn't exist.   Fragments

7:Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.2.1.0\content\libs/internal_impl-23.2.1.jar doesn't exist. Fragments

8:Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.2.1.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.   Fragments

9:Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.2.1.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.   Fragments

10:Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.2.1.0\content./ doesn't exist.   Fragments

---

Can someone explain me why i get those errors and how i can solve it step by step?

PS: I already downloaded the m2repository_r28 and delete the library in Xamarin folder, and paste in there.

I delete all inside folder "zip" clean and rebuild... and i get these errors:

---

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Fragments, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(377,2): error XA5207: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.2.1.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(377,2): error XA5207: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.2.1.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(377,2): error XA5207: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.2.1.0\content\libs/internal_impl-23.2.1.jar doesn't exist.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(377,2): error XA5207: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.2.1.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(377,2): error XA5206: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.2.1.0\content./ doesn't exist.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(377,2): error XA5207: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.2.1.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(377,2): error XA5206: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\GabrielGomes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.2.1.0\content./ doesn't exist.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

---

Solution:

Delete all folders, inside Xamarin like Xamarin.Android and rebuild the solution.

Comment: See this guide I wrote: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

Comment: Hey Jon, i made it, but not solve my problem! do you have Skype?

Comment: You have problems with packages, they are not installed correctly. You need  to install them in right way. Check them in your Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

1. Delete everything from AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips
2. Rebuild the solution

Note: It's important that not matter how long it takes to build you let it complete.

The reason of that error is that when you first install the Support Libraries (any of them) they are downloaded into that directory as a zip file. The downloaded file could be corrupted for many reasons. Just deleting the files and Rebuilding the solution will re-download them.

Comment: OK, but i need to delete only data entire the "zips" folder... but about the others folder for example... Xamarin.Android.Support.V7, cannot i touch in that folders?

Comment: You could delete them as well as they are the unzipped version.

Comment: Ok, I will delete all them, and try to rebuild... Thanks

Comment: Do not forget to Clean then Rebuild your solution.

Comment: Yes, i made it 3 times, Clean and Rebuild the solution, and i still get these errors :'(

Comment: @GabrielGomes let's see if we can find your issue: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135530/xamarin-android-fragments-libraries

Comment: I cannot to talk because... look the message "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here'

Comment: but i have skype gabriel.gomes0504

Comment: Thanks dor the solution.